# A regex to match a 9 digit number if an '&' does not immediately follow the number

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match a 9 digit number but not match if the number is immediately followed by an &. For example:

`randomText123456789RandomText` will return `123456789`
but `randomText123456789&RandomText` will not return anything

Comment: You can use: [`\d{9}(?!&)`](https://regex101.com/r/oJu9xh/1)

Comment: @anubhava submit an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\d{9}(?!&)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJu9xh/1/)

`(?!&)` asserts that next character is not a `&`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want Javascript-style regex, what you are looking for is `/\d{9}(?!&)/`
If you need 9 and need to ensure that it is no longer than 9, you can also do `/(^|\D)\d{9}(?!&)/`

The second one checks if it is either the start of a string or a non-digit, then checks for exactly 9 digits, and will refuse to accept if there is an & following - both end of string and anything but an & will be seen as valid here.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]{9}[^&]*$
```

e.g.:

```
echo 'randomText123456789' | grep -E '[0-9]{9}[^&]*$'
randomText123456789

echo 'randomText123456789RandomText' | grep -E '[0-9]{9}[^&]*$'
randomText123456789RandomText

echo 'randomText123456789&RandomText' | grep -E '[0-9]{9}[^&]*$'
```

(That is, the third command yields no output.)